# How can I replace the last word using Regex?

Tags: regex, swift

I have a String extension:

```
func replaceLastWordWithUsername(_ username: String) -> String {
    let pattern = "@*[A-Za-z0-9]*$"
    do {
        Log.info("Replacing", self, username) 
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)
        return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: username )
    } catch {
        return self
    }
}

let oldString = "Hey jess"
let newString = oldString.replaceLastWordWithUsername("@jessica")
```

newString now equals `Hey @jessica @jessica`.  The expected result should be `Hey @jessica`

Comment: Does it have to be via regex?

Comment: No , but it's preferred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because the `*` [regex operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression) will

> Match 0 or more times. Match as many times as possible.

This might be causing it to also match the 'no characters at the end' *in addition* to the word at the end, resulting in two replacements.

As mentioned by @Code Different, if you use `let pattern = "\\w+$"` instead, it will only match if there are characters, eliminating the 'no characters' match.

```
"Word1 Word2"
        ^some characters and then end
            ^0 characters and then end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
(?<=\s)\S+$
```

Sample: https://regex101.com/r/kGnQEM/1

> /(?<=\s)\S+$/g
>
> **Positive Lookbehind (?<=\s)**
>
> Assert that the Regex below matches
>
> \s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
>
> \S+ matches any non-whitespace character (equal to [^\r\n\t\f ])
>
> - Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> $ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line
>   terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your pattern:

```
let pattern = "\\w+$"
```

- `\w` matches any word character, i.e `[A-Za-z0-9]`
- `+` means one or more